# ASP.NET Update variable from code behind passing to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

This is my pseudocode aspx:

```
<Panel>
 <UpdatePanel>
  <DropDownList onselectedindexchanged="itemSelected"/>
  <Button onClientClick="Validate()" />
 <UpdatePanel>
<Panel>
```

Code behind:

```
void itemSelected()
{
//update VariableFromCodeBehind
}
```

and java script for user side validation:

```
<script>
function Validate(sender, target){
    var variable = <%=this.VariableFromCodeBehind%>;
    //some code
}
</script>
```

How to update "VariableFromCodeBehind" in JavaScript when DropDownList item is changing and updates UpdatePanel?

This aspx code is Modal Popup (ModalPopupExtender from AJAX Control Toolkit). I need variable from code behind for user side validation script. This variable is changing when DropDownList is changing.

Comment: This is tagged with webforms but you're talking about views like if this was MVC. Why? In webforms you don't need Javascript for updating a variable. Are you aware of that?

Comment: @derloopkat I updated question

Comment: Pseudocode is uselss in your situation. You must provide the actual markup you are using else it's impossible to answer.